# How do you get out of the 'transit tube' in Claptastic Voyage?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

In the Claptastic Voyage DLC, you move around parts of it in this 'high speed transit tube' (for lack of a better term).  I realize I appear to have missed some content in one of the sub-areas and would like to go back and see what's out there.  However, this means somehow getting out of the tube, which I can't figure out.

Is there a way to get out of the transit tube once you are in it?

Comment: Try and hold down the key you have the oz kit slam bound on, or possibly the walk back button. (Can't remember which it is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to slam down to the ground, where you'd like to land. Also you can press the button (or the move-stick, if playing on console) to walk back, what will slow down your transport. That will make the landing with the slam attack way easier. On the xbox controller, you slam with the 'B'-button, on the ps controller with the 'O'-button. On PC, I think it's the shift key, you need to press.